# how to put panel div above image div responsively using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to place a panel div above a div which contains an image.
the panel div should be about 20 px to the left and 20 px down from the div below which contains an image.
doing it probably is by declaring the panel div with position:absolute and defining top and left with relevant data.
But doing so will eventally disable the responsivness that bootstrap is relying on.
and by reducing the screen resolution the panel div is being cut.
here is the html code for the 2 divs as I wrote.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <img src="images/back_purp.png" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="position:absolute;top:20px;left:20px;">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
                <img src="images/image-back.png" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

please help, Many thanks in advance for any assistance :)

Comment: Hi, can you provide the css code your working with.

Comment: your html does not seem to render as you explained. the panel div (second row div) will be positioned based on container not the back_purp image. can you show an image from what you want. [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzue3z4o/)

Comment: I understand. even if I am putting the second div inside the div with row class (line number 2), the top and left are based on the div with the row class and not the container which is the right thing to do, BUT the behavior still remains. I want that the panel will be shown as a floating panel above the purple image, and when i am reducing the screen resolution it still keep the responsive behavior. Hope I explained myself better :)

Comment: Guy, i don't use css code besides what i have in the above code and bootsrap css file